# Controlling Threejs camera with both device orientation and touch

Tags: javascript, 3d, three.js, user-controls

I'm fairly new to 3D programming and all the math behind it, right now I have it working fine when either using device orientation or touch events to move the camera, but the way I implemented this one overrides the other. Who can I make both work together? I'm using quaternions to set the camera position, so I'm basically trying to make the touch events work on top of the device orientation events.

The code for the device orientation:

```
  onDeviceMotionChange(deviceMotion) {
    this.alpha = TMath.degToRad(deviceMotion.alpha);
    this.beta = TMath.degToRad(deviceMotion.beta);
    this.gamma = TMath.degToRad(deviceMotion.gamma);
  }

  update() {
    this.euler.set(this.beta, this.alpha, -this.gamma, 'YXZ');
    this.deviceOrientation.setFromEuler(this.euler);

    this.deviceOrientation.multiply(this.centralizer);
    this.camera.quaternion.copy(this.deviceOrientation);
  }
```

And the code for the touch/mouse:

```
  onMouseMove(event) {
    this.rotateEnd.set(event.clientX, event.clientY);
    this.rotateDelta.subVectors(this.rotateEnd, this.rotateStart);
    this.rotateStart.copy(this.rotateEnd);

    this.phi += (2 * Math.PI * this.rotateDelta.y / this.renderer.height * 0.5);
    this.theta += (2 * Math.PI * this.rotateDelta.x / this.renderer.width * 0.6);
   }

  update() {
    this.euler.set(this.phi, this.theta, 0, 'YXZ');
    this.dragOrientation.setFromEuler(this.euler);
    this.camera.quaternion.copy(this.dragOrientation);
  }
```

Comment: Hey Thiago, did you manage to find a solution for this problem?

Comment: Hello Navaneeth, I'll try to provide an answer here based on how I managed to implement it, in the mean time you can check the code here: https://github.com/thiagopnts/kaleidoscope/blob/master/src/controls.js#L108-L158

Comment: Thanks for the repo Thiago, I see you are using your own custom 'threejs360'. How is it different from the original library?

Comment: It's a hand-picked build with only the minimum necessary for doing 360, with this its possible to have a really small resulting bundle